# Pre-rendering a CSS filter transition?

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-filters

Is it possible to pre-render the transition from this:

```
filter:blur(10px) grayscale(100%) brightness(50%);
```

...to this:

```
filter:blur(0) grayscale(0) brightness(100%);
```

I want a smooth transition, but now the FPS is annoyingly low. See the example below, **in full page mode**. (Tested using NVIDIA GeForce GT 240M on a Full HD screen, so your faster GPU might not be weak enough to be as slow as mine.)

```css
div {
  background-image: url('https://static.pexels.com/photos/1998/sea-landscape-mountains-nature.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  -webkit-filter: blur(10px) grayscale(100%) brightness(50%);
  filter: blur(10px) grayscale(100%) brightness(50%);
  height: 1080px;
  transition: all 1s;
  width: 1920px;
  will-change: filter;
}
div:hover {
  -webkit-filter: blur(0) grayscale(0) brightness(100%);
  filter: blur(0) grayscale(0) brightness(100%);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: I know I could use pre-rendered images, but  I need a CSS-only solution, or at least something fully client-side.

Comment: try adding this style : `-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
    -moz-transform: translateZ(0);
    -ms-transform: translateZ(0);
    -o-transform: translateZ(0);
    transform: translateZ(0);`

Comment: I've tried it, but unfortunately it doesn't help.

Answer (score 4):

I suspect there's no golden bullet for this, as browsers will probably always have slightly differing implementations of filters, and visually heavy effects like `blur()` will probably always be problematic. That said—there is a CSS property called `will-change` that is for exactly this situation:

```
.my-element {
  will-change: filter;
}
```

The `will-change` property does not trigger a prerendering per se, but it does give supporting browsers a heads-up that the `filter` property of this element will change at some point, and gives them time to optimize. This usually results in the creation of a new hardware-backed rendering layer in supporting browsers, and thus a smooth animation.

Support is not super-great as of right now, but still: latest Chrome & Opera (including on Android) as well as latest Firefox. WebKit has implemented, so it will likely ship in the next Safari. For others, the `transform`-hack mentioned in the comments usually has a similar effect (as it triggers a hardware-backed rendering layer by adding a null 3D-transform), but your mileage may vary.

Comment: The will-change property is useful, but unfortunately it doesn't help in this case. I've updated the question with a demo, so you will probably be able to see the problem. (Except if your machine is faster than mine.) My final solution was a simple cheat: I've made a blured, darkened, grayscale version of the original photo in a photo editor software, and I animate opacity instead of filter. It works perfectly. Still, I hope there will be a "client side CSS filter transition pre-renderer" in the future, so that more spectacular effects will be possibe.